# EditorFor with Enum named Color not using editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I have a property named `Color` of type `Enum` named `Color`, and I'm trying to use an editor template. My enum editor template is:

```
@ModelType System.Enum

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(Function(model) model, New With {.Class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model, "", New With {.Class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

This works for every property except `Color` which gets rendered as:

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid"
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="The Color field is required."
       id="Color"
       name="Color"
       type="color"
       value="Black"
       aria-describedby="Color-error"
       aria-invalid="false">
```

`@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.AnyOtherEnumProperty)` works exactly as expected, but `@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Color)` results in the HTML color input above. How can I get MVC to use the proper editor template?

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue, manually specify the editor template's name like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Color, "Enum")
```